# Dynamic refresh of a web page reading a DB using PHP HTML AJAX. Is t the right way?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a PHP page with some html that is showing some tables with data taken from a DB. The data is constantly changing so every few seconds the whole page is reloaded..

I would like to interrogate the DB and change only the part of the HTML where the data is shown without reloading the whole page.

There is a best practice to achieve this goal? Can you point me to some guide or give me some hits?I thought i could use ajax call but i'm a newbie.

Thank you for your time and, eventually, answers

Comment: Interrogate the database?! Go easy on em :) A good start would be to post some code. You can achieve this exactly the way you are suggestion. I would recommend JQuery. https://jquery.com Their AJAX function calls are very easy to use.

Comment: @SuperKevin jQuery is bloated. Using window.fetch is better. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your needs, you can achieve this with:

- Long Polling to make asynchronous calls to refresh X seconds a specific set of data for instance (uses Javascript): https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/
- Websockets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

I think it depends on the tools you want to use / are using and your experience.

If you're newbie in Ajax, it could be a good start because the implementation is easier and more understandable to me.

NB: even it's a good start, you have to take into account that asynchronous calls to your db may affect your server performances. This article compares both methods and I think it's a good start to understand the differences, etc. : http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling

Comment: I like the idea of long polling. I'm implementing it and is working.TY